# How to make div expand to screen resolution not content?

Tags: html, css

[This](http://www.jongarza.me) is the website I am developing, the right-side sidebar should expand to the bottom of different screen resolutions using `height:100%;` but for some reason that I can't identify, it only expands to the content in it. Could anyone figure out a solution?

Grab the code from the website if possible if not then ask me to post it.

Comment: provide code for you question

Comment: `height: 100%;` is defined, so from what I know it will only extend as long as there is text, which has happened in your case

Comment: a possible **bad** solution would be to set `height: 855px;` of your `.bodybg` css class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add full height to html and body too:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```